# oracle modify timestamp value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called BRANCHES, it has attribute TSTAMP of type TIMESTAMP that I want to modify. The following statement results in 'ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option'. What is wrong?

```
alter table BRANCHES modify TSTAMP TIMESTAMP'2010-01-10 09:00:00.00224455'
```

Don't throw stones, I'm new to databases.

**EDIT1.**
Thanks to sstan's comment I figured out that I have to use update command. So now I do:

```
update BRANCHES set TSTAMP = TIMESTAMP'2015-01-10 09:00:00.00224455'
```

I get no errors, but TSTAMP is not updated.

**EDIT2.** After commiting everything worked as expected! Thanks!

Comment: You want to modify the *data*, not the column definition, right?  Then use an `update` statement.  Not an `alter` statement.

Comment: What tool are you using to perform the update?  How did you check that it didn't update anything?  Did you commit the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Use an update statement to change all the data, not altering the column type itself.

```
update BRANCHES set TSTAMP = TIMESTAMP'2015-01-10 09:00:00.00224455';
commit;
```